# Merge multiple columns into single column using sql

Tags: sql, netezza

I have data into below format  :

```
 Col1     Col2     Col3      Col4
 ABC      12         34        45
```

I want output as below :

```
Col1    Col2

ABC      12 
ABC      34
ABC      45
```

Comment: Do you need it as an export tool or do you plan to use the output in your application? For the later case it seems better to adjust your database schema than to use unions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use union:

```
select col1, col2
union all
select col1, col3
union all
select col1, col4
```

Comment: Thanks for solution. My query is very big and I need to repeat it every time if I am using UNION ALL. Please let me know if there is any other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to dynamically generate the `sql` consider the following:

```
select 'union all select col1, '||  column_name || ' as col2 from ' || table_name
from _v_odbc_columns1
where table_name = '<table name>'
and ordinal_position >=2
order by ordinal_position
```